# Assign Derived Pointer to a Different Derived Type in C++

Tags: c++, class, oop, pointers, inheritance

Is there a way to change a pointer to a derived object to point to a different type of derived object if they share the same base class? I understand that it would work with a base class pointer, but I am somewhat stuck with what I've got in my current situation.

Example:

```
struct a {};
struct b : a {};
struct c : a {};

int main()
{
  b* ptr = new b;
  ptr = new c;
}
```

Comment: no, it's not allowed. `b` is not `c`

Comment: You can of course do it with a cast, but don't.

Answer (score 0):

No. ( not allowed and clearly leads to more problems if you cast Apple as an Orange )

You maybe new to C++.

Imagine you had a variable in your

struct b : a { int x; };

And

struct c : a { };
had no variable like your example code.

By using b's ptr as c ( if you get around compilor error by casting )
you will try and access variable x that does not exist in c.

Comment: You literally told me it might be possible, then insinuate I cannot do it and I am new to C++. Astounding.

Comment: Sam, that was not my intention. You can do a lot of things in C++ that are not right or should not be done. Your example code will not compile and therefore I said "No" at the very begining. And even if you fix this ( wrongly by casting ) you will have more problems and that is what is explained.

Comment: Sorry then for the misunderstanding. My intention was to permanently change the type of ptr to type c. It is hard to illustrate in a minimum working example, but no b object would ever again be referenced beyond this point in execution, so I actually would not run into this error.